# How can i design my own control in VS 2010 from scratch?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, custom-controls

I wish to design my own control in C# for visual studio.I have followed the link [Create Custom Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2016/Writing-your-Custom-Control-step-by-step) and would like to see some more which involves making control from scratch

Comment: winforms, webforms, or what?

Comment: @JohnSaunders That would be for WinFroms

Comment: From scratch? You mean machine code, right?  :-)

Comment: By Scratch I mean is defining custom events for the control.A simple example would be that of a Devexpress XtraGrid which has CustomDrawFooter event which we do not have in simple Windows Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple search on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%23+create+custom+control) and [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+create+custom+control) are a great place to start.

If you are wanting to create a control that handles its own rendering, you may want to look into using the objects in the [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace (namely [System.Drawing.Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx)).